# Как сделать Gif файл из изображений и сохранить его?

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, анимация, gif

У меня есть массив где хранятся пути ко всем изображениям.
Нужно объединить эти изображения в .gif и сохранить получившийся gif файл.
***Как это сделать?***

```
    if (!Directory.Exists("Изображения\\Анимация"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("Изображения\\Анимация");
    }
    string[] filesPath = Directory.GetFiles("Изображения");
    for(int i = 0; i < filesPath.Length; i++)
    {
         Image img = Image.FromFile(filesPath[i]);
         //Create Gif
    }
FileStream fs = new FileStream("Изображения\\Анимация\\1.gif",FileMode.Create);
gif.Save(fs);//Сохранить полученную выше анимацию
```

Comment: Искать пробовали? Что-то [сомневаюсь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1196322)...

Comment: Как сделать более гибкую настройку, например установить количество кадров в секунду?

Comment: Я не думаю, что стандартным .net будет легко подобное сделать. По той ссылке смотрите например 2-й ответ, там вроде как сделана реализация задержки. Сможете повторить? Сомневаюсь... Так что советую вам найти библиотеку, которая будет делать это все за вас (вроде там же люди советовали необходимые). Также на просторах интернета нашел [этот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET) проект, можете покопаться в его коде и реализовать необходимое у себя.